# SQL query through an imported database swift

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, swift, fmdb

So I have imported a pre-made SQLite database into my application and according to the path set (that you see in the picture labeled "ThePath") the application can open the database. I imported the database by just dragging and dropping it into my App like i read online in other tutorials and I have the FMDB wrapper to help to handle all the database implications of everything as you can also see from all the objective-C files.

So after I saw i could open my database I tried to get a direct SQL query going as you can see in the code below but it says that it can't find the table name that I put in (See the error in bottom left). When I do the query in my SQL browser and my android app it comes out fine but here it doesn't seem to see anything.

Bottom Line: Does anybody see something wrong with this picture? Did i put the database in the wrong place or am i opening it wrong? please help as I am super new to swift!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your table name is "Greek Mythology"? Separated by blank space?

Comment: Yeah, I just copied it from my android app and it has the same database and the statement worked there. It also worked in my SQL database browser. The statement works i was thinking that maybe there was something wrong with the database itself or with how it was put in the app.  When i open the database though it has all the tables and everything so im not sure

Comment: Ok, you can list all table names that you have in your database to show if the table exists. [Here](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7) you can see how to do.

Comment: Thanks Eliana for the quick response. I ran the sql statement and it went good but how do i print it out on swift to get the table names. When i do `println(results)` it just gives me this: <FMResultSet: 0x7fe311c16440>

Comment: I FOUND THE PROBLEM! Apparently the path is wrong but I don't know how to fix it and I haven't found anything online. The path that worked is "/Users/thomaskutay/Desktop/Learning C with Rossi/Insight/Insight_1/Insight_1/Insight1-0.db" but I can't ship that out for an app....can I?

Answer (score 0):

In your line of Path, you are using:
`("insight1-0", ofType: "sqlite")`.

That should be:
`("insight1-0", ofType: "db")`